# Good Hashing Function

Tags: c, hashtable, hash-function

I'm looking to make an hashtable to store some data that I need to access quickly instead of iterating through a linked list and I'm having problems defining a good hash function.

Consider S as the hashtable.

I initialize S[1<sup>0</sup>] with labels (0,...,0) and S[1<sup>w<sub>1</sub></sup>] = (v1<sub>1</sub>,v1<sub>2</sub>)

then I have two loops, j=2 to N, a=0 to W.

N and W can be any positive integer.

In there, I do S[j<sup>a</sup>] = addSomeDifferentStuff(S[(j-1)<sup>a</sup>]), creating the node S[j<sup>a</sup>].

I really can't find a hash function that doesn't create collisions, a friend of mine has suggested  hash = j + a * W.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Ok, so I to clarify myself. This was a implementation of solution on the bi-criteria 0.1 knapsack problem based on a labeling algorithm that converts the knapsack problem to a shortest path problem. W is my capacity, and n is the number of items. Consider w<sub>j</sub> the weight of item j.

Inside of the loops, I'm verifying if the item can be added, if it is then I'll make S[j<sup>a</sup>] = S[(j-1)<sup>a-w<sub>j</sub></sup>] + values[j<sub>1</sub>,j<sub>2</sub>], and otherwise I just copy S[j<sup>a</sup>] = S[(j-1)<sup>a</sup>]. But accessing the labels in S[(j-1)<sup>a</sup>] or S[(j-1)<sup>a-w<sub>j</sub></sup>] is expensive with linked lists since I need to iterate through every element until I find it. That is the purpose of the hashtable.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but there are books on algorithms that have good starting points for hash functions.  You should just take one of those and run it through your data to try first.

Comment: All hash functions create collisions if the hash space is smaller than the input space.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I follow your notation or your algorithmic description.  Are you using the `^` symbol in its normal C sense of the bitwise and operator?  And if `S` is the hash table, then I don't understand why you are computing its elements based on the values of other elements.

Comment: Also, I don't follow the purpose of the loops.  I suppose that they are generating objects to store in the hash table, but what are those objects?  The values `j^a`?  If so, then you do realize, do you not, that you are generating fewer distinct values than you have (`j`, `a`) pairs?

Comment: Correction: `^` as the bitwise exclusive or.  Sorry, it's late here.

Comment: Ok, I have added an update. Sorry for the confusion. If it still persists I can post the pseudo code of the algorithm.

Comment: Do check whether my edit correctly captured the expressions you were trying to present.

Comment: So in fact S is not a hash table, but rather an *array* of hash tables, yes?

Comment: Your editing is correct, thank you! at the present moment, S is an array of linked lists. However I want to change it into an hashtable where the key is j**a so that I access the labels in it faster.

Answer (score 0):

> N and W can be any positive integer.

Well that's surely going to present a computability problem.  You seem to be asking how to construct a perfect hash function for objects consisting of pairs of integers drawn from the ranges 0 ... N and 0 ... W, respectively.  Such a function must compute `(N + 1) * (W + 1)` distinct values, and the bounds on N and W affect the suitable data types and algorithms.

Note, too, that it is probably most useful to consider the keys to be integer *pairs*, not integer *powers*, because N and W don't need to get very large before the powers involved are too large to be represented by any built-in type offered by your implementation.  The pairs will be easier to work with on several levels.

> a friend of mine has suggested hash = j + a * W.

I suppose your friend meant hash(j,a) = j + a * (N + 1).  Provided that it does not overflow, that will produce a different value for each pair (j, a) drawn from the ranges specified.  Alternatively, you could also use hash(j,a) = j * (W + 1) + a, subject to the same proviso about overflow.  If indeed you need a perfect hash function over the full domain you've described, then I don't see much room for improvement over that on the performance side, except possibly by replacing the multiplication with a suitably-large left shift.

The values of those functions do vary with a and j in a completely systematic way, however, and that would be an undesirable characteristic for some uses of such a function.  Finding a perfect hash function that does not have that property is a difficult problem.  One typically would use a program  such as [`gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html) for such a task but that's not amenable to dynamic adaptation to different values of N and W.

---

Note that although that answers the question that I think you actually asked, I'm not certain it's what you are really looking for.  Inasmuch as you seem to have rejected my characterization of `S` as an array of hashtables, instead going back to it being a singular hashtable, I suspect that you mean something different by the term "hashtable" than I do.  Nevertheless, I take the question to be about the hash function, and the use to which you put that function is a separate concern.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe look at https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash for both xxHash, and its list of competing hash functions.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).